# User defaults not saving, not retrieving data

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am successfully using user defaults on other pages of my app, it works like you would expect. In this specific controller I've called a method from a struct with parameters and assigned that as a constant. As far as I can tell, for some reason this configuration will not save or retrieve data from user defaults. I am sure there is a way but I don't know the proper way. Some guidance would help a lot here.

So, I'm trying to save textfields to user defaults and call textfield data as well as method once app reloads so that user has all old data back in tact. Right now nothing happens, I can't even print to troubleshoot if anything gets saved because I really don't know how to print saved state. Noob here.

So far I have tried moving the saving point to various places, before method call on button press, after call, tried inserting user defaults into struct method also, all no go! I've also tried various retrieval methods in view did load but no go so far.

Here is where my code sits currently, non-operational user default saving:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    area.delegate = self
    volume.delegate = self
    height.delegate = self
    
    // Check to see if there is a saved state, if there is then use those numbers and run method for even gauge
    let savedArea = StateManager.retrieveClearCalcValue(key: StateManager.areaKey) as? Double
    let savedVolume = StateManager.retrieveClearCalcValue(key: StateManager.volumeKey) as? Double
    let savedHeight = StateManager.retrieveClearCalcValue(key: StateManager.lengthKey) as? Double
    
    // If there is data in saved states, set text fields to saved data and call calculate
    if (savedArea != nil) && (savedVolume != nil) && (savedHeight != nil) {
        
        area.text = String(savedArea!)
        volume.text = String(savedVolume!)
        height.text = String(savedHeight!)
        
        let result = zoneCalc.clearCalc(area: Double(area.text!), volume: Double(volume.text!), height: Double(height!))
        
        areaBorder.text = String("\(result.0) mm")
        areaBorderLabel.text = "Cut result:"
    }
}
```

Button:

```
@IBAction func calcButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // Resigns keyboard once button pressed
    self.view.endEditing(true)

        // State save attempt
        StateManager.saveClearZone(area: Double(area.text!), volume: Double(volume.text!), height: Double(height!))
    
        let result = clearCalc.clearZoneCalc(area: Double(area.text!) ?? 1.0, volume: Double(volume.text!) ?? 1.0, height: Double(height!))
        
        areaBorder.text = String("\(result.0) mm")
        areaBorderLabel.text = "Cut result:"
    
}
```

EDIT (adding save struct):

```
struct StateManager {

static var unitAreaKey = "UnitArea"
static var unitVolumeKey = "UnitVolume"
static var unitHeightKey = "UnitHeight"

// Saving user data
static func saveClearCalcState(area: Any, volume: Any, height: Any) {
    // Call reference to user defaults
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    // Save state data
    defaults.set(area, forKey: unitAreaKey)
    defaults.set(volume, forKey: unitVolumeKey)
    defaults.set(height, forKey: unitHeightKey)
}

// Retrieve user data
static func retrieveClearCalcValue(key: String) -> Any? {
    //Call reference to user defaults
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    return defaults.value(forKey: key)
}
}
```

Comment: The code is not related to `UserDefaults` at all. How can we know what this `zoneCalc` and `StateManager`stuff is?

Comment: fixed that... zoneCalc is just a calculator that crunches some numbers taken from text fields...

Comment: Inside `calcButtonPress` the method `StateManager.saveClearZone` gets called but there's no such method in the code you provided, could you please add it?

Comment: fixed that, that wasn't the problem. That was my typo when posting this morning after a long night shift. I have to change my code to post because it contains sensitive intellectual property... to put it simply: the above code works well saving user state inside a function call in view controller, however in this configuration i try to save after and before struct method call i am having trouble... Should I be saving the entire struct method call? Can that be done?     ...my apologize for the conundrums, still getting used to how to post on here.

Comment: Got it to print saved values in viewDidLoad and it looks like only one of the three prints value and others print nil... I have triple checked my code its good. Whats going on? help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be that conversion from String to Double sometimes fails on this line (assuming that instead of `saveClearZone` you meant to write `saveClearCalcState`):

```swift
StateManager.saveClearZone(area: Double(area.text!), volume: Double(volume.text!), height: Double(height!))
```

The Double's initializer from a string is failable, meaning it can return `nil` if conversion from a string to a number fails. It can fail because of a wide range of issues like a trailing space or a non-strict format.

Below are a few recommendations how to fix it.

#### Use strictly typed function arguments and avoid `Any`

Currently, your save method accepts `Any` but if you know that you only want to save your data when the user typed in all values correctly, then use `Double` instead:

```swift
static func saveClearCalcState(area: Double, volume: Double, height: Double)
```

If you change the argument types to `Double`, your code will no longer compile because initializers like `Double(area.text!)` return `Double?` and you'll have to unwrap the optionals first to check that the values are valid, which is a good opportunity to let the user know if their input can't be processed.

If your intention is to just save whatever the user typed in just to preserve the state between launches, you may choose `String?` instead of `Any`. Whatever your choose instead of `Any` will declare the usage of the method much clearer.

#### Use `NumberFormatter` to convert strings to numbers

The `NumberFormatter` class provides much more flexibility for this task. For example, you can convert the numbers that the user typed in in their current locale. Say, if your user is in a country where a comma is used as a decimal separator, `NumberFormatter` will let them use their preferred way of typing numbers while the `Double` initializer always requires a full stop symbol as a decimal separator.

#### Use optional chaining instead of force unwrapping

Your code contains a lot of force unwrapping (the exclamation point operators).
Remember that an attempt to force-unwrap a `nil` will crash your app.
It may be fine in some cases, but it wouldn't be nice to crash the app just because a text field doesn't have any text in it.

Prefer [optional chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) to force unwrapping.

#### Example of graceful nil handling

```swift
@IBAction func calcButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // Resigns keyboard once button pressed
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    
    guard let areaText = area.text, !areaText.isEmpty else {
        // TODO: alert the user that area can't be empty
        return
    }
    
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    
    guard let areaValue = numberFormatter.number(from: areaText)?.doubleValue else {
        // TODO: alert the user that the text they entered can't be recognized as a numeric value
        return
    }
    
    //...
    //... do the same checks for volume and height
    //...

    // State save attempt
    StateManager.saveClearZone(area: areaValue, volume: volumeValue, height: heightValue)

    let result = clearCalc.clearZoneCalc(area: areaValue, volume: volumeValue, height: heightValue)

    areaBorder.text = String("\(result.0) mm")
    areaBorderLabel.text = "Cut result:"    
}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed post, I definitely learned something with number formatter, i applied it. I am also handling optionals by coalescing. I am still having problems! The ultra simplicity of key and value saving is being messed up somehow. So as of now I tried many new things like number formatting into strings, thats all that saves now, saving doubles returns nil for all keys. Also saving strings is wacky, it will save key 1 value perfect but 2 and 3 are always different, sometimes the second last values i entered... don't make sense. I even tried using .syncronize() - nope.

Comment: @AppMonster, I edited my answer by including an example of how I'd be handling nils in such situation. If you've done something like that and still experience problems, please attach the actual code that doesn't work and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: changed my post below with all code. Still not working, still racking my head over this. Any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

@Vadim, firstly thanks again for the detailed post. Learned a lot again and applied your optional handling, I will be using these methods from now on. Very succinct!

With regards to the problems with user defaults... STILL HAVING THEM. This is driving me NUTS. I have tried so many different things I can barely list them all but I will try here:

I have:

- Re-wrote the State manager struct 3 times and changed many different things and attempted all sort of different data type handling
- Moved the save state point around in the code many times and to many different points
- Downloaded a cocopod "Defaults" which ended up having exactly the same problem as UserDefaults
- I've changed my view did load method AT LEAST 10 times with many different configurations
- Tried all sorts of optional nil handling as of now

What is going wrong:

- No matter what configurations of code I get the same weird data retrieval, because I'm writing the values to the text fields on reboot if not nil I can see values (also printing them). And consistently the 1st textfield is correct but the second and third are incorrect. Sometimes the 2nd and 3rd will show the last data i entered but not most recent reboot data. Like it lags behind one reboot. Example:

Attempt one:
Field 1: 12345
Field 2: 1234
Field 3: 123
Reboot--

Load:
Show-
Field 1: 12345
Field 2:
Field 3:
New data entry attempt:
Field 1: 54321
Field 2: 5432
Field 3: 543
Reboot--

Show-
Field 1: 54321
Field 2: 1234
Field 3: 123

WTF?

Also I must state that this exact state works perfectly for 6 other view controllers and using the exact same struct methods for saving and retrieval. Only difference is in this VC I made a class for the calculator and the others the calculator is small so its in the VC declared and called as a function with no parameters...

Anyway here is my FULL code for the VC, unaltered, if you care to help I would be much obliged and will push forward the favour in the future when I am knowledgable:

```
//  Copyright © 2020 Roberto B. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CutCalculatorViewController: UIViewController {

// Length cut user inputs
@IBOutlet weak var overallLength: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var unitLength: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var headJointSize: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var metricImperialLengthSelector: UISegmentedControl!
// Length cut labels
@IBOutlet weak var buttonSelectorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var courseOneCut: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var courseOneCutLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var courseTwoCut: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var courseTwoCutLabel: UILabel!


// Height cut user inputs
@IBOutlet weak var overallHeight: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var unitHeight: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bedJointSize: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var metricImperialHeightSelector: UISegmentedControl!
// Height cut label
@IBOutlet weak var heightCutResult: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    if StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.overallLengthKey) != nil && StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.unitLengthKey) != nil && StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.headJointSizeKey) != nil && StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.unitLengthSelector) != nil && StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.unitLengthSelector) as? Int == 0 {
        
        let savedOverallLength = StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.overallLengthKey) as? Double
        let savedUnitLength = StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.unitLengthKey) as? Double
        let savedHeadJoint = StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.headJointSizeKey) as? Double
        metricImperialLengthSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        
        print(savedOverallLength!)
        print(savedUnitLength!)
        print(savedHeadJoint!)
        print(metricImperialLengthSelector.selectedSegmentIndex)
        
        
        overallLength.text = String(savedOverallLength!)
        unitLength.text = String(savedUnitLength!)
        headJointSize.text = String(savedHeadJoint!)
        
        let result = cutCalc.metricRunningBondCalc(overallLength: savedOverallLength!, unitLength: savedUnitLength!, headJointSize: savedHeadJoint!)
        
        courseOneCut.text = String("\(result.0) mm")
        courseTwoCut.text = "N/A"
        courseTwoCut.textColor = UIColor.clear
        courseTwoCutLabel.textColor = UIColor.clear
        buttonSelectorLabel.text = "Stack bond cut result"
        courseOneCutLabel.text = "Cut result:"
    } else if StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.overallLengthKey) != nil && StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.unitLengthKey) != nil && StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.headJointSizeKey) != nil && StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.unitLengthSelector) != nil && StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.unitLengthSelector) as? Int == 1 {
        
        let savedOverallLength = StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.overallLengthKey)
        let savedUnitLength = StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.unitLengthKey)
        let savedHeadJoint = StateManager.retrieveCutCalcValue(key: StateManager.headJointSizeKey)
        metricImperialLengthSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        
        print(savedOverallLength!)
        print(savedUnitLength!)
        print(savedHeadJoint!)
        print(metricImperialLengthSelector.selectedSegmentIndex)
        
        
        overallLength.text = savedOverallLength as? String
        unitLength.text = savedUnitLength as? String
        headJointSize.text = savedHeadJoint as? String
        
        let result = cutCalc.imperialRunningBondCalc(overallLength: savedOverallLength as! Double, unitLength: savedUnitLength as! Double, headJointSize: savedHeadJoint as! Double)
        
        courseOneCut.text = String("\(result.0) inches")
        courseTwoCut.text = "N/A"
        courseTwoCut.textColor = UIColor.clear
        courseTwoCutLabel.textColor = UIColor.clear
        buttonSelectorLabel.text = "Stack bond cut result"
        courseOneCutLabel.text = "Cut result:"
        
    }
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// Initialize cut calculator structure
let cutCalc = CutCalculator()

// Initialize metric imperial segments
var unitLengthMeasurement: Bool = true
var unitHeightMeasurement: Bool = true

// Length cut buttons
// Stack bond- DONE
@IBAction func stackBondLength(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // Resigns keyboard once button pressed
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    
    // Activate methods for cut calculation metric/imperial & label changes
    if unitLengthMeasurement == true {
        
        guard let overallLength = overallLength.text, !overallLength.isEmpty else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Empty field!", message: "All text fields must contain data.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            return
        }
        
        guard let unitLength = unitLength.text, !unitLength.isEmpty else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Empty field!", message: "All text fields must contain data.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            return
        }
        
        guard let headJoint = headJointSize.text, !headJoint.isEmpty else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Empty field!", message: "All text fields must contain data.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            return
        }
        
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        
        guard let overallLengthValue = numberFormatter.number(from: overallLength)?.doubleValue else {
            // TODO: alert the user that the text they entered can't be recognized as a numeric value
            return
        }
        
        guard let unitLengthValue = numberFormatter.number(from: unitLength)?.doubleValue else {
            // TODO: alert the user that the text they entered can't be recognized as a numeric value
            return
        }
        
        guard let headJointValue = numberFormatter.number(from: headJoint)?.doubleValue else {
            // TODO: alert the user that the text they entered can't be recognized as a numeric value
            return
        }
        let unitSelectorValue = metricImperialLengthSelector.selectedSegmentIndex
        
        StateManager.saveLengthCutCalcState(overallLength: overallLengthValue, unitLength: unitLengthValue, headJointSize: headJointValue, measurementLengthSelector: unitSelectorValue)
        
        let result = cutCalc.metricRunningBondCalc(overallLength: overallLengthValue, unitLength: unitLengthValue, headJointSize: headJointValue)
        
        courseOneCut.text = "\(result.0) mm"
        courseTwoCut.text = "N/A"
        courseTwoCut.textColor = UIColor.clear
        courseTwoCutLabel.textColor = UIColor.clear
        buttonSelectorLabel.text = "Stack bond cut result"
        courseOneCutLabel.text = "Cut result:"
        
        // Popup alert
        if result.0 < 36.0 {
            // First instantiate the UIAlertController
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Small cut!", message: "Depending on conditions you may be able to open or squeeze head joints to eliminate this small cut.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            // Add action buttons to it and attach handler functions if you want to
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            
            // Show the alert by presenting it
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        
    } else {
        
        guard let overallLength = overallLength.text, !overallLength.isEmpty else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Empty field!", message: "All text fields must contain data.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            return
        }
        
        guard let unitLength = unitLength.text, !unitLength.isEmpty else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Empty field!", message: "All text fields must contain data.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            return
        }
        
        guard let headJoint = headJointSize.text, !headJoint.isEmpty else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Empty field!", message: "All text fields must contain data.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            return
        }
        
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        
        guard let overallLengthValue = numberFormatter.number(from: overallLength)?.doubleValue else {
            // TODO: alert the user that the text they entered can't be recognized as a numeric value
            return
        }
        
        guard let unitLengthValue = numberFormatter.number(from: unitLength)?.doubleValue else {
            // TODO: alert the user that the text they entered can't be recognized as a numeric value
            return
        }
        
        guard let headJointValue = numberFormatter.number(from: headJoint)?.doubleValue else {
            // TODO: alert the user that the text they entered can't be recognized as a numeric value
            return
        }
        let unitSelectorValue = metricImperialLengthSelector.selectedSegmentIndex
        
        StateManager.saveLengthCutCalcState(overallLength: overallLengthValue, unitLength: unitLengthValue, headJointSize: headJointValue, measurementLengthSelector: unitSelectorValue)
        
        let result = cutCalc.imperialRunningBondCalc(overallLength: overallLengthValue, unitLength: unitLengthValue, headJointSize: headJointValue)
        
        courseOneCut.text = "\(result.0) inches"
        courseTwoCut.text = "N/A"
        courseTwoCut.textColor = UIColor.clear
        courseTwoCutLabel.textColor = UIColor.clear
        buttonSelectorLabel.text = "Stack bond cut result"
        courseOneCutLabel.text = "Cut result:"
        
        // Popup alert
        if result.2 < 2.5 {
            // First instantiate the UIAlertController
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Small cut!", message: "Depending on conditions you may be able to open or squeeze head joints to eliminate this small cut.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            // Add action buttons to it and attach handler functions if you want to
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            
            // Show the alert by presenting it
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

// Running bond- DONE
@IBAction func runningBondLength(_ sender: Any) {
    // Resigns keyboard once button pressed
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    
    // Activate methods for cut calculation metric/imperial & label changes
    if unitLengthMeasurement == true {
        let result = cutCalc.metricRunningBondCalc(overallLength: Double(overallLength.text!) ?? 1.0, unitLength: Double(unitLength.text!) ?? 1.0, headJointSize: Double(headJointSize.text!) ?? 1.0)
        courseOneCut.text = String("\(result.0) mm")
        courseTwoCut.text = String("\(result.1) mm")
        buttonSelectorLabel.text = "Running bond cut results"
        courseTwoCut.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7333333333, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)
        courseTwoCutLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7333333333, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)
        courseOneCutLabel.text = "Course 1 cut:"
        courseTwoCutLabel.text = "Course 2 cut:"
        
        // Popup alert
        if result.0 < 36 || result.1 < 36 {
            // First instantiate the UIAlertController
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Small cut!", message: "Depending on conditions you may be able to open or squeeze head joints to eliminate this small cut.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            // Add action buttons to it and attach handler functions if you want to
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            
            // Show the alert by presenting it
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    } else {
        let result = cutCalc.imperialRunningBondCalc(overallLength: Double(overallLength.text!) ?? 1.0, unitLength: Double(unitLength.text!) ?? 1.0, headJointSize: Double(headJointSize.text!) ?? 1.0)
        courseOneCut.text = String("\(result.0) inches")
        courseTwoCut.text = String("\(result.1) inches")
        buttonSelectorLabel.text = "Running bond cut results"
        courseTwoCut.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7333333333, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)
        courseTwoCutLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7333333333, green: 0.8823529412, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)
        courseOneCutLabel.text = "Course 1 cut:"
        courseTwoCutLabel.text = "Course 2 cut:"
        
        // Popup alert
        if result.2 < 2.5 || result.3 < 2.5 {
            // First instantiate the UIAlertController
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Small cut!", message: "Depending on conditions you may be able to open or squeeze head joints to eliminate this small cut.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            // Add action buttons to it and attach handler functions if you want to
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            
            // Show the alert by presenting it
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

// Height cut button- DONE
@IBAction func heightCut(_ sender: Any) {
    // Resigns keyboard once button pressed
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    
    // Activate methods for cut calculation metric/imperial & label changes
    if unitHeightMeasurement == true {
        let result = cutCalc.metricHeightCutCalc(overallHeight: Double(overallHeight.text!) ?? 1.0, unitHeight: Double(unitHeight.text!) ?? 1.0, beadJointSize: Double(bedJointSize.text!) ?? 1.0)
        heightCutResult.text = String("\(result) mm")
        
        // Popup alert
        if result < 30.5 {
            // First instantiate the UIAlertController
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Small cut!", message: "Depending on conditions you may be able to gain or squeeze to eliminate this small cut.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            // Add action buttons to it and attach handler functions if you want to
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            
            // Show the alert by presenting it
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    } else {
        let result = cutCalc.imperialHeightCutCalc(overallHeight: Double(overallHeight.text!) ?? 1.0, unitHeight: Double(unitHeight.text!) ?? 1.0, beadJointSize: Double(bedJointSize.text!) ?? 1.0)
        heightCutResult.text = String("\(result) inches")
        // Popup alert
        if result.1 < 2.5 {
            // First instantiate the UIAlertController
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Small cut!", message: "Depending on conditions you may be able to gain or squeeze to eliminate this small cut.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            // Add action buttons to it and attach handler functions if you want to
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            
            // Show the alert by presenting it
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

// Length cut calculator metric imperial selector- DONE
@IBAction func lengthUnitSelector(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if (metricImperialLengthSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        unitLengthMeasurement = true
    } else {
        unitLengthMeasurement = false
    }
}

// Height cut calculator metric imperial selector- DONE
@IBAction func heightUnitSelector(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if (metricImperialHeightSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        unitHeightMeasurement = true
    } else {
        unitHeightMeasurement = false
    }
}

// Acts to dismiss number keyboard when user taps outside
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    overallLength.resignFirstResponder()
    unitLength.resignFirstResponder()
    headJointSize.resignFirstResponder()
    overallHeight.resignFirstResponder()
    unitHeight.resignFirstResponder()
    bedJointSize.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

}

Here is my saving class:

```
// Cut calculator saved states
static var overallLengthKey = "OverallLength"
static var unitLengthKey = "UnitLength"
static var headJointSizeKey = "HeadJointSize"
static var unitLengthSelector = "LengthUnitSelector"

static var overallHeightKey = "OverallHeight"
static var unitHeightKey = "UnitHeight"
static var bedJointSizeKey = "BedJointSize"
static var unitHeightSelector = "HeightUnitSelector"

// Saving user data
static func saveLengthCutCalcState(overallLength: Double, unitLength: Double, headJointSize: Double, measurementLengthSelector: Int) {
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(overallLength, forKey: overallLengthKey)
    defaults.set(unitLength, forKey: unitLengthKey)
    defaults.set(headJointSize, forKey: headJointSizeKey)
    defaults.set(measurementLengthSelector, forKey: unitLengthSelector)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
// Saving user data
static func saveHeightCutCalcState(overallHeight: Double, unitHeight: Double, bedJointSize: Double, measurementHeightSelector: Int) {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(overallHeight, forKey: overallHeightKey)
    defaults.set(unitHeight, forKey: unitHeightKey)
    defaults.set(bedJointSize, forKey: bedJointSizeKey)
    defaults.set(measurementHeightSelector, forKey: unitHeightSelector)
}

// Retrieve user data
static func retrieveCutCalcValue(key: String) -> Any? {
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    defaults.synchronize()
    
    return defaults.value(forKey: key)
}

// Clear state
static func clearLengthCutCalcState() {
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    // Clear the saved state data in user defaults
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: overallLengthKey)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: unitLengthKey)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: headJointSizeKey)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: unitLengthSelector)
}
static func clearHeightCutCalcState() {
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    // Clear the saved state data in user defaults
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: overallHeightKey)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: unitHeightKey)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: bedJointSizeKey)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: unitHeightSelector)
}
// DONE- Even gauge calcualtor saved states -DONE
```